# Cannot build website, Visual Studio 2008 errors on build (temp files)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, build-process

<strike>All of the errors are on auto-generated files, not within the files that were created by me.  Here are a few of them:</strike>

```
'Context' is not a member of 'auth_cookies'
'ProcessRequest' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a sub in a base class
'Server' is not a member of 'ASP.auth_cookies_aspx'
Class 'auth_cookies_aspx' must implement 'Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: found out that the file it was looking for wasn't there, fixed that problem and that eliminated all the errors except one:

```
 Error-5: There can be only one 'page' directive.
 >> C:\Users\darren\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\gs_ontheweb\auth\cookies.aspx
```

This is the contents of the **`cookies.aspx`** page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/theMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="cookies.aspx.vb" Inherits="auth_cookies" title="NOM COOKIES" %>
```

UPDATE: Turns out one of linked files had a link to another .aspx page, causing 2 page directives to be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put a `<%@Page%>` directive in your Master page?  It should only have a `<%@Master%>` directive.

Comment: Your comment got me thinking, found out the solution.  Thanks

Comment: I originally was thinking about asking about the Page directive being on some other included page.  But I assumed you weren't including other pages if you're using Master pages.  :)  Glad you found it in any case.

Answer (score 0):

No, the header of my MasterPage is:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="theMaster.master.vb" Inherits="theMaster" %>
```

There is no `<%@Page%>` directive on the MasterPage.